# How to return the value from Entry，at the same time, destroy widow?

Tags: python, tkinter, return-value, tkinter-entry

My English is not good。
I want to use a button to return value from Entry，tkinter，at the same time ，destroy the root.
Like Vba function input.
My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, title, default):
        self.HEIGHT = 150
        self.WIDTH = 300
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.width = self.WIDTH
        self.root.height = self.HEIGHT
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, height=self.HEIGHT, width=self.WIDTH)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=title)
        self.label.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
        self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.2, anchor="center")

        self.content=tk.StringVar()
        self.content.set(default)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root, font=('helvetica', 20), justify='center', textvariable=self.content)
        self.entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.3, anchor="center")
        self.entry.focus_set()

        # Here is the button call to the getInfo() function
        self.buttonInputBox = tk.Button(self.root, text="Yes", bg='#cccccc', font=60,
                                        command=lambda: self.getInfo())
        self.buttonInputBox.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3, anchor="center")

        self.root.mainloop()

    def getInfo(self):
        return self.entry.get()
        self.root.destroy()

def main():
    print(InputBox('RP', 'haha'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Change to `self.entry_value = self.entry.get()` and change in `main` to `ib = InputBox(... ; print(ib.entry_value)`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was wrong at the beginning .because it‘s a class,in __init__,only return itself, not a value.i should use a def or other ways like app.input() etc..

Comment: Read about [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) the common usage for your task.